# Need a way to handle the 2/3 byte VEX in C# assembler

Tags: c#, assembly, bit-manipulation, bit-fields, machine-code

Hello there I have fully ported the x86 assembler (and auto assembler) from cheat engine to c#.

Everything works fine for the most part however the "VEX" prefix instructions are currently broken.

There is 2 sections of code I wasn't able to convert just yet so I wonder if anybody can provide a solution to it.

Commented out sections are the ones that I'm not sure how to deal with.

2 byte vex

```
//2byte vex
bytes.SetLength(bytes.Length + 2);
for (i = bytes.Length - 1; i >= RexPrefixLocation + 2; i--)
    bytes[i] = bytes[i - 2];
bytes[RexPrefixLocation] = 0xc5; //2 byte VEX
//pvex2byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->pp = (int) (Assembler.OpCodes[j].VexLeadingOpCode);
//pvex2byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->l = Assembler.OpCodes[j].VexL;
//pvex2byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->vvvv = vexvvvv;
//pvex2byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->r = RexR ? 0 : 1;
if (RelativeAddressLocation != -1)
    RelativeAddressLocation += 2;
```

3 byte vex

```
//3byte vex
bytes.SetLength(bytes.Length + 3);
for (i = bytes.Length - 1; i >= RexPrefixLocation + 3; i--)
    bytes[i] = bytes[i - 3];
bytes[RexPrefixLocation] = 0xc4; //3 byte VEX
//pvex3byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->mmmmm = (int)(Assembler.OpCodes[j].VexLeadingOpCode);
//pvex3byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->b = RexB ? 0 : 1;
//pvex3byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->x = RexX ? 0 : 1;
//pvex3byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->r = RexR ? 0 : 1;
//pvex3byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->pp = (int)(Assembler.OpCodes[j].VexLeadingOpCode);
//pvex3byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->l = Assembler.OpCodes[j].VexL;
//pvex3byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->vvvv = vexvvvv;
//pvex3byte(&bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1])->w = RexW ? 1 : 0; //not inverted
if (RelativeAddressLocation != -1)
    RelativeAddressLocation += 3;
```

The original assembly/auto assembler is made in pascal (lazarus) and here is the definition of the pvex3byte

```
  TVEX3Byte=bitpacked record
    mmmmm: 0..31;
    B: 0..1;
    X: 0..1;
    R: 0..1;
    pp: 0..3;
    L: 0..1;
    vvvv: 0..15;
    W: 0..1;
  end;
  PVEX3Byte=^TVEX3Byte;

  TVEX2Byte=bitpacked record
    pp: 0..3;
    L: 0..1;
    vvvv: 0..15;
    R: 0..1;
  end;
  PVex2Byte=^TVex2Byte;
```

Can somebody solve how to fill this part in? If possible a complete class or extension for the "bytes" (byte[]) array to allow editing/reading the vexs properly?

I figure its something to do with bits, unfortunately there's no bit struct in c# (none that work in this way).

Comment: Have you looked at the [`BitArray` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=net-5.0) yet? It allows you to create/manipulate a set of bits and [copy it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.copyto?view=net-5.0) into a `byte[]` afterwards. I'm not sure about its performance, though. In case it's too slow, you could try the [`BitVector32` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32?view=net-5.0).

Comment: The fastest option is to get a pointer to `bytes[RexPrefixLocation + 1]` (you can do this in `unsafe` blocks) and set the values similar as it's done in the original code. But instead of e.g. `->l` you'd have to use bit masking.

Comment: I'm aware it can be done with unsafe blocks etc I'm also aware its handled by bit masking the problem is I dont know the correct masks to read/write the values.

Comment: Could you add what you tried/know so far to the question?

Comment: My guess is that your code didn't consider your platform's endianness. For instance a `TVEX2Byte` where everything is zero except `R` might be `000_0_0000|00000000|0000_1_000` (big endian, `_` are pack boundaries, `|` are byte boundaries, the last 3 bits `_000` are padding) or it might be `0000_1_000|00000000|000_0_0000` (little endian, most likely your endianness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding this on github

```
    /* VEX 2 byte form */
    /*  7                           0    */
    /* +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ */
    /* |~R |     ~vvvv     | L |   pp  | */
    /* +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ */

    /* VEX 3 byte form */
    /*   7                           0     7                           0    */
    /* +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+*/
    /* |~R |~X |~B | map_select        |   |W/E|    ~vvvv      | L |   pp  |*/
    /* +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+*/
```

Then some help from a friend and my custom vec() class was quickly able to solve the problem.

The end result was a new multiByte class that handles the vex2/3 with simple properties.

```
    public class AVex3Byte : AMultiByte
    {
        #region Constants
        private const int SIZE = 2;
        #endregion
        #region R
        public Byte R
        {
            get => (Byte)Get(7, 1, true);
            set
            {
                Set(7, 1, true, value);
                Apply();
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region X
        public Byte X
        {
            get => (Byte)Get(6, 1, true);
            set
            {
                Set(6, 1, true, value);
                Apply();
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region B
        public Byte B
        {
            get => (Byte)Get(5, 1, true);
            set
            {
                Set(5, 1, true, value);
                Apply();
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Mmmmm
        public Byte Mmmmm
        {
            get => (Byte)Get(0, 5, true);
            set
            {
                Set(0, 5, true, value);
                Apply();
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region W
        public Byte W
        {
            get => (Byte)Get(15, 1, true);
            set
            {
                Set(15, 1, true, value);
                Apply();
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Vvvv
        public Byte Vvvv
        {
            get => (Byte)Get(11, 4, true);
            set
            {
                Set(11, 4, true, value);
                Apply();
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region L
        public Byte L
        {
            get => (Byte)Get(10, 1, true);
            set
            {
                Set(10, 1, true, value);
                Apply();
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Pp
        public Byte Pp
        {
            get => (Byte)Get(8, 2, true);
            set
            {
                Set(8, 2, true, value);
                Apply();
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Constructor
        public AVex3Byte()
            : base(SIZE)
        {
        }
        public AVex3Byte(AByteArray bytes, int index)
            : base(SIZE, bytes, index)
        {
        }
        public AVex3Byte(IntPtr bytesPointer)
            : base(SIZE, bytesPointer, 0)
        {
        }
        public AVex3Byte(IntPtr bytesPointer, int index)
            : base(SIZE, bytesPointer, index)
        {
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Heres how the original question code looks upon fixing

```
//2byte vex
bytes.SetLength(bytes.Length + 2);
for (i = bytes.Length - 1; i >= RexPrefixLocation + 2; i--)
    bytes[i] = bytes[i - 2];
bytes[RexPrefixLocation] = 0xc5; //2 byte VEX
var vex2 = new AVex2Byte(bytes, RexPrefixLocation + 1);
vex2.Pp = (Byte)Assembler.OpCodes[j].VexLeadingOpCode;
vex2.L = Assembler.OpCodes[j].VexL;
vex2.Vvvv = (Byte)vexvvvv;
vex2.R = (Byte)(RexR ? 0 : 1);
if (RelativeAddressLocation != -1)
    RelativeAddressLocation += 2;
```

```
//3byte vex
bytes.SetLength(bytes.Length + 3);
for (i = bytes.Length - 1; i >= RexPrefixLocation + 3; i--)
    bytes[i] = bytes[i - 3];
bytes[RexPrefixLocation] = 0xc4; //3 byte VEX
var vex3 = new AVex3Byte(bytes, RexPrefixLocation + 1);
vex3.Mmmmm = (Byte)(Assembler.OpCodes[j].VexLeadingOpCode);
vex3.B = (Byte)(RexB ? 0 : 1);
vex3.X = (Byte)(RexX ? 0 : 1); 
vex3.R = (Byte)(RexR ? 0 : 1);
vex3.Pp = (Byte)(Assembler.OpCodes[j].VexLeadingOpCode);
vex3.L = Assembler.OpCodes[j].VexL;
vex3.Vvvv = (Byte)vexvvvv;
vex3.W = (Byte)(RexW ? 1 : 0); //not inverted
if (RelativeAddressLocation != -1)
    RelativeAddressLocation += 3;
```

What I needed was the correct information about what bits and where they are and how big they are and how to read/write to/from it.

Comment: `private const int SIZE = 2;` for `AVex3Byte`?  Is that a bug, or just counting bytes after the fixed `c4` first byte?   BTW, a smarter VEX class would be able to decide for itself if it could be written out as a 2-byte or 3-byte VEX prefix.  (Depending on what fields were set; if any of the fields not present in a 2-byte VEX needed a non-default value.  Typically for instructions that need more mandatory-prefix bits, or if the 2nd source needs a high bit in the register number.  e.g. `vpxor xmm15, xmm0,xmm0` is a more compact way to zero YMM0 than `vpxor xmm15, xmm15,xmm15`)

Comment: Its correct (size 2 since theres 2 bytes after the op code -- 3 total if you include it which there is no point doing so). the OP Code is not included in it since its a given and doesnt need to be there. (Notice RexPrefixLocation + 1), It could easily do both byte types in one class however there simply isnt any real point and why bother showing v3 properties when you just want to edit a v2.

Comment: The point would be that whether you need a VEX2 or a VEX3 depends on the operands, 
so if you're writing an assembler, having the VEX logic itself decide whether it can use a compact prefix or not is a good place to put that logic.  Otherwise you need some other code that knows all about VEX prefix internals to decide what the shortest possible encoding of an instruction is.  (Which is what any good assembler should do, unless you override it like GAS `{vex3} vpxor xmm0, xmm0, xmm0` to force a VEX3.)

Comment: Ohhh snap, I totally misunderstood that e.g. `pp: 0..3;` doesn't mean the field has a size of 3 bits, but that the field can take values from 0 to 3. Thanks for posting your answer!